# Disable PhpDoc by Default in PhpStorm Extract Method Refactoring Dialogue

Tags: ide, phpstorm, phpdoc

I've searched PhpStorm's preferences, documentation, and Google to no avail.

Is there a way to disable by default the "Generate PhpDoc" option in PhpStorm's "Extract Method" dialogue?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an ancient post, but I struggled with the same question today.  In PHPStorm 2017.1 the setting is here:

Preferences > Editor > Intentions > PHP > Generate PHPDoc for function

Comment: I wish it was that easy! This only takes it out of the `alt + return` intentions menu. Extracting a method still generates the docs by default.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a tickbox when you use the Extract Method intention which says `Generate PhpDoc`. If you refactor once with this option unticked, it stays unticked.